# Entity Framework Core - how to insert nulll value into a non-null column but assigned default value?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core to insert data into a SQL Server table. The class is defined as shown below.

In the database, the `CreateDate` is a non-null column and with a default value `GETDATE()`.

```
public class ItemSoldPrice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
}
```

It creates an object and doesn't give any value to `CreateDate`, so it is null. I think while saving into database, it should use database's default value. But it throws error after invoking `DbContext.SaveChanges()`.

> Cannot insert null into column CreateDate.

Is there any way to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: Read about Generated Values: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations

Comment: This question does get at one of the big problems with heavy ORM's like EF: Who's responsible for the domain logic? EF wants you to be able to pretend there's no SQL database, but that's a voluntary delusion. As David's link shows, EF in some cases requires you to couple the database and the EF model together so tightly that you're putting the T-SQL default as code in EF (the `getdate()`example). The fact that the sample trigger code on that page is a flawed trigger that only works in a non-set-based manner should make you wary about whether you "trust" EF.